# How do I download GCC source?

Tags: gcc

I'm trying to get the GCC source for 4.9.1 to compile it on `debian`. I googled "How to install GCC" which directed me to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/).

There, under [Downloading the source](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html), it claims that GCC is distributed via SVN, linking to [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html). It provides the following command for downloading the GCC trunk repo:

```
svn checkout svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk SomeLocalDir
```

Except I want the latest release, not the trunk branch. Further down on that page it gives this as an example for how to get a specific branch:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/branchname gcc
```

So I installed `subversion` and tried replacing `branchname` with `gcc_4_9_1_release` (and a bunch of other combinations that I won't bother listing) which produced this error:

```
svn: URL 'svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9_1_release' doesn't exist
```

Anyway that same [downloads page](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/download.html) has another link to a supposed [releases page](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) which contains a list of dead links that presumably hosted GCC at one point or another.

I don't remember it being this hard. If someone could let me know how they obtained this exclusive software I'd be grateful.

Comment: You can try to use `svn` to find the latest release branch with this `svn ls svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches` and then check it out with `svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/branchname gcc`

Comment: Not really sure why this got downvoted. Finding GCC source code is bafflingly difficult; I come back to this page all the time...

Comment: I think the question is downvoted since it is not a programming question. While it may be answered here but it's not the right place and it does not fit the stackexchange topics.

Comment: "*it's not the right place and it does not fit the stackexchange topics*" - [I disagree](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). On the first few lines of the help center it clearly states that "*If your question generally covers... software tools commonly used by programmers and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development... then **you’re in the right place to ask your question**!*"... Seems on topic to me!

Comment: You are right, I had missed that. Then I don't have a good guess on why someone would downvote this question. Since I myself had struggle with downloading gcc in the first time, it seemed to be a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `svn ls svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches` to see all branches. You will then see the latest branch for GCC is *gcc-4_9-branch/*.

Then use the svn to checkout the latest branch. In this case it will be:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9-branch gcc
```

You will then be able to compile it using the make file provided.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the latest release, it's probably easier to download a tarball from the ftp site.

Currently it's under ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-4.9.1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line to see what releases are available:

```
svn ls svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags | grep gcc | grep release
```

And then download a release as:

```
svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_5_1_0_release/
```